# Do users get more reputation for edit on an answer with score > X?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, reputation, edits

I met [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832230/a-b-b?tab=reputation) and I saw he just received +4 reputation for one single edit 2 days ago.

I'm curious, is there anything behind this behavior is it just a favorite cache/"recalculation needed" problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is always just +2. The user's profile shows +4 because he has two edits that were approved for that question on that day. See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7061193/revisions).

Comment: Damn. That makes sense. I didn't think about this situation

Comment: @genesis You can also click the [triangle-expando thingy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBCX9.png) on the rep page that you linked to

Comment: @ConradFrix: I can't. [Look](http://phpcode.eu/images/1319220614.png)

Comment: @genesis hmm that's weird. Maybe you lose that ability when you get to 20K? or maybe you need to refresh your browser

Comment: @ConradFrix: No. I just used "by time" sorting and it somewhat forgot to pluralize the word

Comment: @genesis wow I had no idea by-time did that